# Particle Creation by a Source

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, s-matrix-theory, wick-theorem

I am currently self-studying Quantum Field Theory and am using the textbook *Introduction to Quantum Field Theory* by Peskin and Schroeder. Currently I am in chapter 4, and am doing the first problem in the chapter exercises. I am using the solutions provided in this link (https://theoreticalmaximum.files.wordpress.com/2017/07/intro-to-qft-solutions2.pdf). In problem 4b (page 18 of pdf) the solution's author claims

> "Since $j(x)$ is not a quantum field, it cannot be contracted with any other states in any meaningful way. Therefore, only the even powers of the exponential Taylor series will contribute to this amplitude."

In part (d) the problem considers $\langle k | ... |0\rangle$ instead of $\langle0|...|0\rangle$ and the solution's author claims

> "Because one of the fields in the series must be contacted with the outgoing state, we see that only odd terms contribute."

I am having a hard time understanding what the author means when we writes this in parts b and d. Can anyone explain to me, mathematically, why odd powered terms would make the integral vanish in part b and why even powered terms would make the integral vanish in part d? Basically I am trying to prove these two claims, but I am having a hard time doing so. Such an explanation will guide me when I try to explain why the author considered the $n + 2p$ powered terms in the part (e).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is problem 4.1 of Peskin. Peskin said in the problem "by a classical source". So we need not worry about the source. It is a C-number rather than a quantum field.

We are concerning amplitudes like
$$\int\cdots\int\; d^4x_1\cdots d^4x_n\;
j(x_1)\cdots j(x_n)\;\langle0|\phi(x_1)\cdots\phi(x_n)|0\rangle.$$
I hope it is self-evident that $\langle0|\phi(x_1)\cdots\phi(x_n)|0\rangle$ is zero when $n$ is odd. Remember that $\phi$ carries $a$ and $a^\dagger$ which cancles either $|0\rangle$ or $\langle0|$, so they must appear in pair as propergators for the integral to be nonzero. While in (d), the term we concern becomes
$$\langle k|\phi(x_1)\cdots\phi(x_n)|0\rangle.$$
So we need an odd number of $\phi$'s. One pair with the $a_k$ in $\langle k|=\langle0|a_k$ and others appear in pair.

There is a solution to Peskin authored by Xianyu Zhongzhi. Maybe it is helpful for you.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation; it was very helpful! Also, thank you for referencing another solution manual